# Visualizing multi-threaded logs

Tags: logging

Is there any tool that helps sorting out multi-threaded logs?
Say I have 8 different threads printing logs at the same time. Those threads might come from thread pools and therefore might be reused.
I was thinking about an app that would represent the logs graphically. First the logs would be printed in whatever format then handed over to this app for debugging.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a framework for Visualizing logs, hope that helps
https://github.com/pablito900/VisualLogs